# jquery click event dont work

Tags: jquery, click

here is the site : http://www.notrepanorama.com
at the bottom left, i use a jquery plugin to make a slideshow from the flickr stream
the plugin is not mine, and i cannot chage the code (encoded), so i like to capture the click event and make anyclick href to open in a new windows after the list of image is done

it's base on this code : http://api.flickrshow.com/v7/

or How to bind the click event AFTER absolutely syre the images are all loaded ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#flickrbox-fs-w").click(function(){ console.log(this)});
```

worked for me in firebug console. If you want to be sure that all IMAges are loaded use window onload.Images are external non dom elements like iframe / video etc ..  document.ready() won't tell you if they are loaded

http://www.think-lamp.com/2010/09/jquery-accessing-iframe-data-and-the-shortcomings-of-document-ready/